# BlazeDS not executing or returning service calls asynchronously

Tags: java, actionscript, blazeds

I have a BlazeDS RemotingService defined in my remoting-config with multiple destinations. In my scenario, I am making three rapid-fire service calls in ActionScript. Two calls correspond to one destination, while the other call corresponds to another destination. However, all three calls execute synchronously on the server, with all of them waiting to return until the last service request is complete. Is this normal behavior? Is it possible to make the service requests execute and return independently from each other?

Answer (score 0):

If you are making three service calls at a same time, then they all will return asynchronously. They will not wait for the last service call to be finished.

But I wont recommend that because in making multiple calls at same time, you have high chance of getting famous  "Duplicate Session" problem. If possible make the calls one after another.

Comment: Actually, that's not true. They do get processed in a synchronous batch if they are called through the same session.